# Where is php.ini file of php_fpm?

Tags: php

I checked all paths location file `php.ini`, made `echo phpinfo();` and got:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/php/lib

But here is not file `php.ini`.

This command from stackovweflow helped me:

> php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"

It gives me path:

> Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

What does this mean? Where can I locate `php.ini?`

Comment: Look at `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` - you should find the file there. If you modify it, make a copy of the file first (`cp /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini.bak`). Once you're done making your changes and everything works fine, you can delete the backup.

Comment: Thank you, may be you will answer me, in version 5.5 PHP is supported Mysql extension? I have error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Comment: It is supported, but in your case, most probably it is not loaded. Run `phpinfo()` and check if it shows up in the list. If not, add it to your list of modules to load.